# Xcode 7.x Simple Full Screen Mode like Sublime/iTerm2

Tags: xcode, sublimetext, iterm2

Is there a specific key binding for Xcode to go into simple full screen without the lion full screen effect? What I mean is when you open up any full screen on a Mac now, it makes its own 'space' and filters everything out. Pretty annoying when you want to run other windows along side it.

In Sublime, you can turn off this feature with the 'use_simple_full_screen' option.

In iTerm2, you can turn off this feature by unchecking under Preferences > General > Use Lion Full Screen Mode

Then when toggling full screen mode there is no unnecessary animations and it just pops into full screen as you please.

Thanks!

Edit: Added similar functionality apps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a specific key binding for Xcode to go into simple full screen without the lion full screen effect?

In any application, you can hold down the Option key and click the green zoom button to get the old fill-the-screen-without-full-screen behavior.

If you assign a keyboard shortcut (say, ctrl-=) to Window->Zoom, then the same shortcut with the Option key added (option-ctrl-=) will give you the behavior you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the functionality that I'm looking for. It's a quick snap into full screen mode without the annoying animations that you see in OS X. I am currently using El Capitain as of this writing. I edited the original post to include iTerm2 which also offers this functionality.